# Proof of Work validation

Tags: transactions, hash-algorithm, architecture

[image]

I am not too understanding this equation. Do any one know it? Especially what is m stand for since I cannot get it from the paper.

Thanks

Comment: For a more in-depth explanation, see [the wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash)

Answer (score 1):

From the [paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) (section 4.4, page 5):

> **mixHash:** A 256-bit hash which proves combined with the nonce that a
>   sufficient amount of computation has been carried out on this block;
>   formally **H<sub>m</sub>**.

See entry (160) in the paper for a complete description of the Proof of Work algorithm, and how the nonce, entry (49), is used.

The step-by-step explanation of the Ethash (i.e. PoW) algorithm on the wiki will also be of help: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash